# PyQt. Get errors trying to separate GUI from logic

Tags: python, pyqt

So I try to separate **GUI part** from **logic part**, but I can't call **logic** function from **GUI part**. Here's the simplified version of the code:

GUI part

```
import logic

class Program(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.first_list = QListWidget(self)
        self.first_list.setGeometry(15, 35, 140, 42)

        add_to_list_button = QPushButton('Add', self)
        add_to_list_button.setGeometry(165, 35, 30, 20)
        add_to_list_button.clicked.connect(lambda: logic.addToList())

        self.second_list = QListWidget(self)
        self.second_list.setGeometry(205, 35, 140, 192)

    for i in range(30):
        self.second_list.addItem(logic.list_one[i][3])
```

And the logic part

```
import gui

# list_one and list_two go here

def addToList(self):
    for i in range(len(gui.Program.second_list)):
        if list_one[i][3] == str(gui.Program.second_list.currentItem().text()):
            index = i

    list_two.append(list_one[index])
```

When I run the code and press the Add button I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/************/gui.py", line 30, in <lambda>
    add_to_list_button.clicked.connect(lambda: logic.addToList())
TypeError: addToList() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

And when I add self and press the button I get:

```
add_to_list_button.clicked.connect(lambda: logic.addToList(self))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**************/gui.py", line 30, in <lambda>
    add_to_list_button.clicked.connect(lambda: logic.addToList(self))
  File "**************/logic.py", line 23, in addToList
    for i in range(len(gui.Program.second_list)):
AttributeError: type object 'Program' has no attribute 'second_list'
```

Plus I get lots of other errors like "Cannot find reference 'connect' in 'function', etc.". When the whole code is in one file it works fine. But I have no idea how to separate it right. Sorry for lots of code examples.

Comment: A few points: you're right to add self to `addToList`.  Simply importing logic in the gui and gui in the logic doesn't make any objects available to you - only the class information and any static values.  Somewhere, you create an instance of the `Program` class.  One way or another, that needs to be injected into your logic.  Your logic shouldn't operate on the class gui.Program, but on an instance of it, e.g. some my_program variable.

Comment: As you're structured right now, you'd need some other process to construct the gui and the logic, and to inject them to each other.  It's usually a lot easier to keep track of what you're doing by having one "own" the other.  When I've done this, I instantiated a logic object, and passed that to the gui.  The logic operates independently (that makes it easy to unit test!), while the gui calls the logic.  It would be worth it for you to take the time to structure the way your two tiers will operate - further development will become much easier if they're not each calling to each other.