# QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget error

Tags: python, pyqt

I have two different files. One contains GUI code and the other one contains a logic of the program. 
The GUI part:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow,  QLabel, QDesktopWidget, QListWidget)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
import logic

class Program(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.first_list = QListWidget(self)
        self.first_list.setGeometry(15, 35, 140, 42)

        add_to_list_button = QPushButton('Add', self)
        add_to_list_button.setGeometry(165, 35, 30, 20)
        add_to_list_button.clicked.connect(lambda: logic.addToList(self))

        self.second_list = QListWidget(self)
        self.second_list.setGeometry(205, 35, 140, 192)

        for i in range(30):
            self.second_list.addItem(logic.list_one[i][3])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Program()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And the logic part:

```
import gui

# list_one and list_two go here

prog = gui.Program()

def addToList(self):
    for i in range(len(prog.second_list)):
        if list_one[i][3] == str(prog.second_list.currentItem().text()):
            index = i

    list_two.append(list_one[index])
```

But when I run the program I get **QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QWidget** error. Adding `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, etc.)` to logic won't help. What's wrong with the code?

Comment: FWIW, I think you are creating a lot of unnecessary problems by trying to structure your program in this way. Use [Qt Designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html) and [pyuic](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to create the gui, and then use a subclass of the main-window for the rest of the program's logic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt. Get errors trying to separate GUI from logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047671/pyqt-get-errors-trying-to-separate-gui-from-logic)

Comment: The user has asked almost the same question already here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41047671/pyqt-get-errors-trying-to-separate-gui-from-logic  Instead of posting multiple question, try to get one single question or delete one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how `prog = gui.Program()` in your `logic` module is being run when you `import logic` from your main program

That means you create a `Program` instance which creates a lot of QWidgets before the QApplication is created in your `__main__`

So, in your logic module:

- Remove `prog = gui.Program()`
- Rework your `addToList()` function to take a `Program` instance as a parameter instead of referring to a global variable

Comment: could you please give an example? because now, when I edited my code I get errors like "Program has no second_list attribute"

Comment: @AndreyK4 All you need in the code you posted is to change `def addToList(self):` to `def addToList(prog):`

Comment: gives me this `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`